# Simple JSON parsing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I've got two pages, **test.php** which encodes a JSON array, and **test.html** which I have using `$.getJSON` to parse the array from the PHP page. Both pages are in the same directory.

test.php:

```
<?php
    for ($x=0; $x<10; $x++){
        $arr[$x] = array('Value1'=>"$x", 'Value2'=>"$x");
    }
        $y = json_encode($arr);
        echo $y;
?>
```

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('test.php', function(data) {
              var items = [];

              $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
              });

              $('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'my-new-list',
                html: items.join('')
              }).appendTo('body');
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html is not successfully parsing any of the JSON data from test.php. Can anyone tell me why this is? Thanks!!

Comment: have you checked the return data in the console? are you sure it returns something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are only iterating over the outer array in your JSON string, and not then over each object literal.  You JSON looks like this:

```
[{"Value1":"0","Value2":"0"},{"Value1":"1","Value2":"1"},{"Value1":"2","Value2":"2"},{"Value1":"3","Value2":"3"},{"Value1":"4","Value2":"4"},{"Value1":"5","Value2":"5"},{"Value1":"6","Value2":"6"},{"Value1":"7","Value2":"7"},{"Value1":"8","Value2":"8"},{"Value1":"9","Value2":"9"}]
```

That's an array, containing a bunch of object literals.  To get to the objects, you'll need something like:

```
$.getJSON('test.php', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  // Iterate first over the outer array
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {

    // Then over the properties of each object contained in the array
    $.each(val, function(innerkey, innerval) {
       items.push('<li id="' + innerkey + '">' + innerval + '</li>');
    });
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

#### Update:

[Here are the guts of this](http://jsfiddle.net/n57KZ/1/) demonstrated on jsFiddle.